# DDP Attribute Value / Parameter Data Type in ArcToolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, parameters, data-driven-pages, arctoolbox

I have created a Python script that exports the DDP pages into single PDFs based on the values of the attribute table. The Python is working fine but now I want to transfer it into an ArcToolbox,

Here is the Python script for reference:

```
import arcpy
# Set the workspace and map document
arcpy.env.workspace = r"path\to\workspace"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"path\to\map\document.mxd")
# Get the data driven pages object and set the output folder
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
output_folder = r"path\to\output\folder"
# Loop through each page and export the map to a PDF
for i in range(1, ddp.pageCount + 1):
    ddp.currentPageID = i
    page_name = ddp.pageRow.getValue("ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    output_file = output_folder + "\\" + page_name + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, output_file)
# Clean up the map document
del mxd
```

Now I want to transfer the Python script into a toolbox based on Python parameters. The issue here is that don't know how to force ArcToolbox to show me the Attributes DDP fields to select the field I'm interested. I could type the attribute field name but I would prefer to have a list and select the relevant field

[image: Screenshot export PDF DDP]

At the moments these are the parameters Data Types:

[image]

Comment: See script validation